# Can mod_rewrite/IIS search multiple file system locations for a requested file?

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis

I am using http://www.isapirewrite.com/ on IIS for added rewrite support. I am unfamiliar with IIS built in alias/rewrite functionality and need help.

I have a file (image.png) that is called from http://files.com/images/image.png. The file is located in the file system within one of three mapped drives ex: C:/images, D:/images, or E:/images.

Can IIS/Mod Rewrite be configured to search multiple directories for a file and return the file without redirects?